# How to repair a ext3 filesystem other than fsck

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3

Are there any specialized/preferred tools to repair a filesystem for ext3 (or ext4) other than fsck.ext3, fsck.ext4?

Thanks

Comment: It's the filesystem that's damaged, or the partition/volume?

Comment: `fsck` is *the preferred* tool to repair filesystems. When it fails, there's the dangerous (as in: use only in emergencies) `fsdb`.

Comment: "other than fsck.ext2, fsck.ext4" - why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I have seen fsck is the best tool there and definitely the price is right! :-)

I'm interested as to what problems you are encountering with this very proven piece of software?